# Create dictionary groups from select SqlAlchemy by column value

Tags: python, mysql, sql, json, sqlalchemy

I need select all rows from table, and organize in groups, by column `my_group`.

For example:

My model class is

```py
class MyTable:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(Unicode(255))
    my_group = Column(Unicode(50), nullable=False)
```

My table is

```
id | label | my_group |
 1 | lbl1  | groupA   |
 2 | lbl2  | groupB   |  
 3 | lbl3  | groupA   |
 4 | lbl4  | groupC   |
 5 | lbl5  | groupC   |
```

I want a result like this

```
[
    {
        "groupA": [
            {
                "label": "lbl1", 
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "label": "lbl3", 
                "id": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "groupB": [
            {
                "label": "lbl2", 
                "id": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "groupC": [
            {
                "label": "lbl4", 
                "id": 4
            },
            {
                "label": "lbl5", 
                "id": 5
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is it possible to accomplish this only with SqlAlchemy?

Thanks!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Is MySQL, @IljaEverilä

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a recent enough version of MySQL, 5.7.22 and later, you can use the [JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html) to produce the desired result:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import JSON

query = session.query(
        func.json_object(
            MyTable.my_group, func.json_arrayagg(
                func.json_object(
                    'label', MyTable.label,
                    'id', MyTable.id)),
            type_=JSON)).\
    group_by(MyTable.my_group)

result = [r for r, in query]
```

If you actually need a dictionary of groups, you can wrap the grouped query:

```
sq = session.query(
        MyTable.my_group,
        func.json_arrayagg(
            func.json_object(
                'label', MyTable.label,
                'id', MyTable.id)).label('arr')).\
    group_by(MyTable.my_group).\
    subquery()

result = session.query(
        func.json_objectagg(
            sq.c.my_group, sq.c.arr,
            type_=JSON)).\
    scalar()
```

Comment: Thank you, my version from MySQL is old :(
Currently i use in this format, this work form me.

`groups = session.query(MyTable.my_group) \
              .distinct(MyTable.my_group).all()

my_dict = {}
    for (g,) in groups:
        my_dict[g] = session.query(MyTable.id, MyTable.label) \
                            .filter(MyTable.my_group == g) \ 
                            .all()`